# JDatePicker - How to change the Icon of the Button?

Tags: java, icons

I'm looking for help in placing an Icon instead of the default three dots as shown in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBtHB.png).

But I really have no clue how I can do it. The Class `DateLabelFormatter` just does some String conversions to display the german calendar names.

```
UtilDateModel modelProjektEnde = new UtilDateModel();
    JDatePanelImpl datePanelProjektEnde = new JDatePanelImpl(modelProjektEnde, dateLabelFormatter.getProperties());
    dateProjektEnde = new JDatePickerImpl(datePanelProjektEnde, dateLabelFormatter);
```

Comment: Assuming you're using [this implementation](https://github.com/JDatePicker/JDatePicker), there is a class called `ComponentIconDefaults`, which is used by the `JDatePicker` to set the buttons icons, the property you are looking for is `setPopupButtonIcon`

Comment: Despite using the jdatepicker-1.3.4.jar, no such class or method was found.

Comment: Download the source from GitHub

Answer (score 0):

simple use this.

> myDateChooser.getCalendarButton().setIcon("calendar.png");

Explaination for starters my be unnecessary here but here we go anyway,

If you want a Calendar or DateChooser in your project. You can use

> JDateChooser.

Follow steps.

1. [Download JCalendar 1.4.jar library](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjcalendar14jar.htm).
2. Add it to your projects library folder by right clicking on Libraries and select ADD JAR/FOLDER.
3. if you are using netbeans then right click on your pallete and select pallete manager.
4. Now select Add from Jar and choose your downloaded libaray and select calendar it's calendar components you want to use. JDateChooser in this case.
5. Drag and drop this from pallete or declare it in your code.

> JDateChooser myDateChooser = new com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser();

to customize the button icon you can use following code

```
    myDateChooser.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Icons/calendar.png")));
```

Replace the path string with your icon path.
To change the button background

```
    myDateChooser.getCalendarButton().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
```

and use can also change foreground, fonts etc this way.